# Sign of momentum in fermion propagator

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, fermions, conventions, antimatter, propagator

Thinking of a process like Compton scattering, where we have an electron as a propagator, I would typically write down the propagator as
$$i \frac{\not q+m}{q^2-m^2}.$$
If I were to replace the electron with a positron, does the propagator become:
$$i\frac{-\not q+m}{q^2-m^2}~?$$

Sort of a silly question, but I'm finding it hard to narrow down the answer with different sign conventions out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, the fermion propagator is

$$ \left\langle 0 \right| T\psi(x)\overline\psi(y) \left|0\right \rangle= S(x-y) = \int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{i}{\not k-m}e^{-ik\cdot(x-y)}$$

Depending on the time ordering, this describes a **particle** moving from $y$ to $x$, *or* an **antiparticle** moving from $x$ to $y$.

---

Now, consider a one-loop diagram in which an external photon decays into a particle and an antiparticle at point $y$, which subsequently annihilate to produce a photon at $x$. Let the momentum appearing in the propagators be $p$ for the photon, $l$ for the particle, and $k$ for the antiparticle.

This diagram has an integral over the positions of the vertices $x,y$; the particle's propagator $S(x-y)$, and the antiparticle's propagator $S(y-x)$; and an exponent $e^{-ip\cdot(y-x)}$ coming from the photon wavefunction. Ignoring vertex factors and polarization vectors, this diagram is

$$ \int d^4x \int d^4y \int \frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{i}{\not l-m}e^{-il\cdot(x-y)}\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{i}{\not k-m}e^{-ik\cdot(y-x)}e^{-ip\cdot(y-x)} $$

Performing the position integrals gives us two identical delta functions $ \delta^4(l-k-p)$, which tell us to set $k=l-p$ in the calculation and drop the $k$ integral, leaving

$$ \int \frac{d^4l}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{i}{\not l-m}\frac{i}{(\not l-\not p)-m} $$

---

In fact wherever there is a vertex, the lines going *into* the point $x$ contribute a $e^{-ip_1\cdot x -...}$, and the lines going *out* contribute a $e^{+ik_1\cdot x+...}$, giving us a delta function $\delta^4(p_1+...-k_1...)$.

Ingoing particles have lines that point into the vertex, and outgoing particles have lines that point out of the vertex, so if a particle $p_1$ scatters off of an ingoing photon $p_2$, then we have a delta function $\delta^4(p_1+p_2-k_1)$, the usual momentum conservation relation that we expect: $k_1=p_1+p_2$.

But ingoing antiparticles have lines that point *away* from the vertex, and outgoing antiparticles have lines that point *into* the vertex, so they always contribute *minus* their momentum. The same process as above gives a delta function $\delta^4(-p_1+p_2+k_1)$, giving $-k_1=-p_1+p_2$. Let us rewrite this,

\begin{align}
&q_1=-p_1, \quad q_2=-k_1 \\&
q_2=q_1+p_2
\end{align}

Now it resembles the normal momentum conservation equation, and we can relate back to the propagator momenta with the above relations.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but can you explain to me what you mean when you say the 'physical momentum I would measure for the positron'? I think it's probably a moot point, but considering this is a propagator, I'm not sure it makes sense to talk about measuring it s momentum.

Comment: @drglove you're right, the virtual particle is just part of the mathematics. I've edited the post with a better explanation of what I meant.

Comment: You say the propagator describes a particle going from y to x or an anti-particle going from x to y. But what if I want to describe an anti-particle going from y to x?

Comment: @Ihle Swap $x$ and $y$ so that $S(x-y)$ becomes $S(y-x)$. $x$ and $y$ are just labels for the vertices.

Answer (score 1):

If q is the momentum for positron, then the propagator for it is still $i\frac{\not{q}+m}{\not{q}^2 - m^2 + i \epsilon}$.